# Calender and Date picker will overlap when i re-size my browser

Tags: javascript, master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I have the following components inside my App part ; a calendar and a date picker (i have moved the datePicket to be in the left side of the screen instead of being on the right side):- 
[image]

And I set the layout for the calendar an the date picker as follow:-

```
.calender
{
 Width:75% !important;

    }

#datepicker{

position:absolute;
right:5%;
top:5%;
}
```

Now If the browser is maximize the layout will be fine , but when I re-size my browser the date picker and the calendar will overlay as follow:-
[image]

**EDIT**
Here is the generated markup from firefox firebug:-
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CSS and layout, not really SharePoint specific. The problem just happens to present it self with SharePoint parts in this case.

Comment: if it is offtopic , then why there is a CSS tag inside Sharepoint forum ?

Comment: @RobertLindgren raises a good point, as well as john. ;) However, I'll see if I can help. How is your calendar and date picker in the page? In DIVs or a TABLE? Can you post some HTML? Usually, in these cases it's a matter of playing with CSS to get it to where you want. I.e., try removing the position property of the #datePicker class.

Comment: can you check my Edit, i have removed the position proprty but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what the exact fix will be. You'll need to play with the display and position properties of both the calendar and the date picker classes to get them to work together properly, and across your multiple browsers.

You may find better success in getting your CSS questions answered on the broader http://stackoverflow.com site.

Comment: i tried posting there, but all the solution well work on some browsers only..

Comment: It's a frustrating process, each browser translates the CSS uniquely. It takes someone who has years of experience to sit down and hash through it, trial and error. :(